# How to determine the order from Auto-Regressive model in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, classification, autoregressive-model

I have time series vibration signal recorded for 10 seconds. I segmented the vibration signal into a number of frames. I need to use an Auto-regressive model for this signal. AR model is used to extract the data from the vibration signal. The goal of an AR model is to estimate the AR coefficient  that can fit the original data as much as possible through an optimization process. I am going to classify the vibration signal using the AR coefficient as the features. In order to find the effective classification accuracy, frame analysis has been done. AR model coefficients are extracted from each frame.

My problem is, how can I develop the AR model? How do I determine the order of polynomial from the AR model? And also how do I find the coefficient?

Perhaps, can anyone provide me the Matlab code for this?

Comment: Hai..How did you find the model parameters first of all without setting up the model? I mean "AR model coefficient are extracted from each frame" how did you do that step?

Comment: Hai @Oliver. thanks for commenting. first, i segmented the signal into 10 frame. so from each frame i am going to extract the AR model coefficient. i noticed in Matlab there are built-in function for Ar model that is 'ar'. so i used the ar built-in function to extract the coefficient. mfb=ar(y1,1,'burg','now'); then i used p=getpvec(mfb); to obtain the coeff. but sir i am not very sure whether i am doing it right or not.

Comment: You specified the model order as 1 (second input argument in ar command). So you might have got only one coefficient. Isn't it?

Comment: @Oliver-yes sir, i ve obtained the order 1 with 1 coefficient. but sir, how do i decide on what order is suitable for my model? because i got almost 120 coeff (extracted features) for 1 sample. how do i decide which order is suitable?

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by feature for one sample. What I understand is that you acquired 10 sec vibration data which is segmented in to many data frames. For each frame you fit an order-1 AR model. Do you have 120 frames so that you obtain 120 coefficients? They are many ways to find model order for a given frame (data samples). Popular one is Akaike information Criterion (AIC).

Comment: Finding exact model order for a given data samples is itself is a well-studied problem in time-series analysis and signal processing. If you want more info.  will let  you know..

Comment: sir @oliver, can u elaborate it more. i want to know. 120 coefficient means i have 3 sensor attached, then i have 4 location places to place my sensor. i take 10 frame each. therefore, there are 120 coeff obtained. yes sir. i wanna know more on how to find the exact model order for a given data samples especially on AR model in Matlab. plus sir, how do i know that my AR model in s-domain or z-domain? thanks for your kind help sir.

Comment: the model with an order 1 AR analysis gives a coefficient of -0.9829,is this coefficient consider to be in s-domain or z-domain sir?

Comment: Please see this http://kr.mathworks.com/help/econ/specify-ar-models.html and find out the domain..I do not know what is s-domain by the way..Why have you specified the model order as 1?

Comment: sir @oliver, i didnt specified yet which order to use. just my random question on why it gives negative coeff. is there any significant. thanks a lot sir oliver.

Comment: It is possible to have negative coefficient.  Coefficient of an AR model depends only on the auto-correlation of the signal (frame of samples in your case). In the AR(1) model (where we have single pole), positive coefficient represents a low-pass AR(1) filter and negative  coefficient a high pass AR(1) filter.

Comment: @oliver, thanks a lot for all your help sir. really useful!

Comment: Best wishes....

Comment: one thing sir @oliver, i ve read in here http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/ar/ on how to determine the order. sir paulbourke stated that by using RMS error plot. how do i plot the 
RMS error in Matlab? how can i extract the information from my raw signal to be compared with my model (for each frame?). for my model i got no problem to analyse. but when it comes to my raw signal, i dont know how to analyse. since i am using frame analysis for my model. any idea sir?